# Problem with solving a linear ODE with a parameter

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, parametric-functions, parameters

I have been struggling with the following ode for several weeks, but I fail to solve it. So I post this question and my attempts and expect someone here could give some suggestions.

First, define an operator and a function:

```
op[r_] = (D[#, {r, 2}] - 1/r*D[#, r]) &;
f0[r_] = 1/2*(2 r^2 Log[r/b] - r^2 + b^2);
```

Next, the ode and 4 boundary conditions:

```
eqn = op[r][op[r][f1[r]]] == -I*(4 - 2*G*(1 + b)^2*Log[r/b] + G/2*(r^2 - b^2)*(1 + (1 + b)^2/r^2));

f1[b] == 0;
f1'[b] == 0;
bc3 = f1''[r] - 1/r*f1'[r] + G*(c*f0[r] - f1[r]);
bc4 = f0'[r] - I*(f1'''[r] - 1/r*f1''[r] + 1/r^2*f1'[r]) + f0[r]/(1 + b)^2;
```

where both `G` and `b` are related to a constant `g` (`0<g<1`, see below), `bc3` and `bc4` are the left-hand sides of the actual boundary conditions both of which vanish at `r=1+b` (`b>0`, see below). Note that `c` in `bc3` is an unknown constant (maybe complex-valued) to be determined. There are also 2 simple bcs at `r=b`, please see below. The ode is defined from `r=b=g/(1 - g)` to `r=b+1=1/(1 - g)`.

My goal is to find `c` and `f1[r]`. **At the very least, I need to find the unknown parameter `c`**. And this is the answer for checking

```
c=I*G/4(G/192*(1+2*b)^2*(41+82*b+30*b^2)-1/8*(1+2*b+5*b^2)*(3+6*b+2*b^2)-3/4*(1+b)^2*(1+2*b)*Log[(1+b)/b]+(1+b)^4*(Log[(1+b)/b])^2)-I/(2*(1+b))*(1/8*((1+2*b)/(1+b))^2-1/G)
```

**Method 1:** direct method

```
sol1 = DSolve[{eqn /. G -> (4*(1 - g)^2)/(g^2 - 2 Log[g] - 1) /. b -> g/(1 - g), (f1[b] /. b -> g/(1 - g)) == 0, (f1'[b] /. b -> g/(1 - g)) == 0,
(bc3 /. r -> (1 + b) /. b -> g/(1 - g) /. G -> (4*(1 - g)^2)/(g^2 - 2 Log[g] - 1)) == 0,
(bc4 /. r -> (1 + b) /. b -> g/(1 - g)) == 0}, f1, (*{r, g/(1 - g), 1/(1 - g)}*) r,
Assumptions -> g > 0 && g < 1 && c != 0]
```

I got an error with the unsolved system returned:

> DSolve::alliv: The function f1[r] was specified without dependence on all the independent variables. Each function must depend on all the independent variables.

**Update on Feb 4 according to Michael's suggestion:**
The warning might arise from specifying a range of independent. By replacing `{r, g/(1 - g), 1/(1 - g)}` by `r`, method 1 produces a solution.

**Method 2**: find a general solution firstly, then use the bcs to determine the unknown constants

```
f1genesol = DSolve[eqn, f1, r, Assumptions -> b > 0 && {b, G} \[Element] Reals] //FullSimplify

(*{{f1 -> Function[{r}, C[4] - 1/384 I r^2 (12 b^2 G + 24 b^3 G + 12 b^4 G - 120 r^2 - 66 G r^2 - 132 b G r^2
- 51 b^2 G r^2 + G r^4 + 192 I C[1] - 96 I C[2] + 96 I r^2 C[3] + 12 ((8 + G + 2 b G) r^2 + 16 I C[2]) Log[r] +
24 b^2 (1 + b)^2 G Log[r]^2 + 60 (1 + b)^2 G r^2 Log[r/b] - 24 (1 + b)^2 G r^2 Log[r/b]^2)]}}*)
```

evaluating the boundary conditions with the general solution and storing in `bcs`

```
BCs = {f1[b], f1'[b], (bc3 /. r -> 1 + b), (bc4 /. r -> 1 + b)};
bcs = BCs /. f1genesol[[1]];
```

using the `bc3` in `bcs` to determine the parameter `c`

```
csol = Simplify[Solve[bcs[[3]] == 0, c], b > 0]
(*{{c -> (-384 I - 768 I b - 384 I b^2 + 96 I b^2 G + 192 I b^3 G + 96 I b^4 G + 65 I G^2 + 390 I b G^2 + 948 I b^2 G^2 +
1192 I b^3 G^2 + 813 I b^4 G^2 + 282 I b^5 G^2 + 38 I b^6 G^2 + 192 G C[1] + 384 b G C[1] + 192 b^2 G C[1] - 384 C[2] -
96 G C[2] - 192 b G C[2] - 96 b^2 G C[2] - 768 C[3] - 1536 b C[3] - 768 b^2 C[3] + 96 G C[3] + 384 b G C[3] + 576 b^2 G C[3]
+ 384 b^3 G C[3] + 96 b^4 G C[3] + 384 G C[4] - 12 I (1 + b)^4 G (-16 + 5 (1 + b)^2 G) Log[1 + 1/b] +
24 I (1 + b)^4 G (-8 + (1 + b)^2 G) Log[1 + 1/b]^2 - 12 I (1 + b)^2 (-64 + (1 + b)^2 (1 + 2 b) G^2 + 16 I G C[2]) Log[1 + b] -
24 I b^2 (1 + b)^4 G^2 Log[1 + b]^2)/(192 G (-1 - 2 b + 2 (1 + b)^2 Log[1 + 1/b]))}}*)
```

Substituting `c` into `bc3` and solving for the constants `C[i]` together with the remaining bcs

```
Solve[bcs[[1]] == 0 && bcs[[2]] == 0 && (bcs[[3]] /. csol[[1]]) == 0 && bcs[[4]] == 0, {C[1], C[2], C[3], C[4]}]
```

But, it gives null.

**Method 3**: find solution with first 2 bcs, then solve the remaining two unknown constants with `Resolve`:

```
sol3 = DSolve[{eqn /. G -> (4*(1 - g)^2)/(g^2 - 2 Log[g] - 1) /. b -> g/(1 - g), (f1[b] /. b -> g/(1 - g)) == 0, (f1'[b] /. b -> g/(1 - g)) == 0}, f1, r, Assumptions -> g > 0 && g < 1] // Simplify

(*Not show the long solution, which includes unknowns C1, C2, C3, C4*)
```

next, using `Resolve` with `Exists` (**Note it runs more than 6 hours before manually aborting**)

```
Resolve[Exists[{C[1], C[2]},
Simplify[(bc3 /. r -> (1 + b) /. b -> g/(1 - g) /. G -> (4*(1 - g)^2)/(g^2 - 2 Log[g] - 1)) /. sol3[[1]]] == 0 && Simplify[(bc4 /. r -> (1 + b) /. b -> g/(1 - g)) /. sol3[[1]]] == 0], Complexes]
```

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Method 1, using `r` instead of `{r, g/(1 - g), 1/(1 - g)}` that is interpreted as specifying three variable (I think), gives me a solution.  Can you use it?

Comment: @Enter Probably parameter `c` could be specified from some condition like `Norm[f1]<Infinity` for any  `0<g<1`. In this regards could you provide some link to the original problem explanation?

Comment: @MichaelE2 thank you for the suggestion. I hope it could work, but it gives a null solution for `c`. Please see my update.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I have double-checked the problem and do not see any extra stuff. This is a question that I rearranged and extracted from multiple problems which are not easy to be combined and linked here.

Comment: @Enter How did you define `c`? See my answer and my different expression for `c`.

Comment: `DSolve` returns a solution such that `bc3` simplifies to `0`; that is, it satisfies the boundary condition. Thus solving `bc3 == 0` is thus equivalent to solving `0 == 0` when the solution is plugged in, and all values of `c` satisfy it.  That is what `Solve[]` indicates by returning `{{}}`. (No solution is indicated by `{}`. Technically `{{}}` indicates  the "solution set is full dimensional" according to the docs, not necessarily that all values are solutions.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 You are right, since determinant of linear system including 4 boundary conditions equals 0. See my answer.

Comment: @MichaelE2 thank you for the explanation. I have updated my post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem could be clarified as follows

```
op[r_] = (D[#, {r, 2}] - 1/r*D[#, r]) &;
f0[r_] = 1/2*(2 r^2 Log[r/b] - r^2 + b^2);
eqn = op[r][
    op[r][f1[r]]] == -I*(4 - 2*G*(1 + b)^2*Log[r/b] + 
      G/2*(r^2 - b^2)*(1 + (1 + b)^2/r^2));

bc1 = f1[b] == 0;
bc2 = f1'[b] == 0;
bc3 = f1''[r] - 1/r*f1'[r] + G*(c*f0[r] - f1[r]) /. {r -> b + 1};
bc4 = f0'[r] - I*(f1'''[r] - 1/r*f1''[r] + 1/r^2*f1'[r]) + 
    f0[r]/(1 + b)^2 /. {r -> b + 1};

sol = DSolve[{eqn, bc1, bc2, bc3 == 0, bc4 == 0}, f1[r], r];

ff = f1[r] /. sol[[1]] /. {G -> (4*(1 - g)^2)/(g^2 - 2 Log[g] - 1), 
    b -> g/(1 - g)} // Simplify
```

Now if we evaluate `Denominator[ff] // FullSimplify` we got 0. We also can evaluate

```
Denominator[ff]

Out[]= 192 (-1 + g)^4 (-1 + g^2 - 2 Log[g]) (Log[1/(1 - g)] + 
   Log[g] - Log[g/(1 - g)])
```

And we see that `(Log[1/(1 - g)] + Log[g] - Log[g/(1 - g)])=0` for `0<g<1`. Therefore we have a problem 1/0 on solution `ff`. To avoid this problem we can first define solution with 4 arbitrary constants and evaluate `bc`

```
s4 = DSolve[eqn, f1, r];

equ1 = bc1 /. s4[[1]];

equ2 = bc2 /. s4[[1]];

equ3 = bc3 /. s4[[1]];

equ4 = bc4 /. s4[[1]];
```

If we try to define constants using linear equations we have

```
{vec, mat} = 
 CoefficientArrays[{equ1, equ2, equ3 == 0, equ4 == 0}, {C[1], C[2], 
   C[3], C[4]}]
```

Please, note, that `vec` in this case has 4 nonzero elements. Therefore solution exits only if determinant not equals zero. Determinant can be computed as

```
det = Det[mat // Normal] // FullSimplify

Out[]= I b (1 + b) (4 + G + 2 b G + 
   2 (1 + b)^2 G (Log[b] - Log[1 + b]))
```

For required `b, G` we have

```
det /. {G -> (4*(1 - g)^2)/(g^2 - 2 Log[g] - 1), 
   b -> g/(1 - g)} // FullSimplify

Out[]= 0
```

It means that there is no unique solution with these boundary conditions. But we can use `c`  to define unique solution as follows

```
ss4 = 
  Solve[{equ1, equ2, equ3 == 0, equ4 == 0}, {C[1], C[2], C[3], c}];

 c4 = c /. ss4[[1]] /. C[4] -> 0 // FullSimplify

Out[]= -((I (48 (10 + b (48 + b (83 + 2 b (32 + b (11 + b))))) - 
       4 (1 + b)^2 (-9 + 
          b (-48 + b (-90 + b (-66 + (-11 + b) b)))) G - (1 + 
          b)^5 (1 + 2 b) (71 + b (142 + 61 b)) G^2 + 
       2 (1 + b)^2 (12 b^2 (1 + b)^3 G Log[
            1 + 1/b]^2 (4 - (1 + b)^2 G + 
             2 (1 + b)^2 G (Log[b] - Log[1 + b])) + 
          6 Log[1 + 1/b] (-8 (6 + b (16 + 3 b (5 + 2 b))) - 
             2 (1 + b) (5 + b (21 + 2 b (17 + 2 b (6 + b)))) G + (1 + 
                b)^3 (5 + b (20 + b (31 + b (22 + 5 b)))) G^2 - 
             2 b^2 (1 + b)^2 (1 + 2 b) G (2 + G + b G) (Log[b] - 
                Log[1 + b])) + 
          b^2 G (-12 (3 + 2 b (4 + b (3 + b))) - (1 + b)^3 (36 + 
                b (72 + 31 b)) G + 
             12 (1 + b)^5 G (Log[b] - Log[1 + b])) (Log[b] - 
             Log[1 + b]))))/(192 (1 + b)^3 G (-1 - 2 b + 
       2 (1 + b)^2 Log[1 + 1/b])))
```

Note `c4` equals to `c` proposed by Enter  on the line `{G -> (4*(1 - g)^2)/(g^2 - 2 Log[g] - 1), b -> g/(1 - g)},C[4]->0}`. Therefore, solution `f1` has a form

```
fsol = First[f1 /. s4[[1]] /. ss4 /. C[4] -> 0 // Simplify]
```

We can plot this function with `r` and `g` as follows

```
f1g = fsol /. {G -> (4*(1 - g)^2)/(g^2 - 2 Log[g] - 1), 
     b -> g/(1 - g)} // Simplify;

Table[Plot[Im[f1g[[2]]], {r, g/(1 - g), g/(1 - g) + 1}, 
  PlotLabel -> g], {g, .1, .9, .1}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Note that evaluation `(c4 - c)/. {G -> (4*(1 - g)^2)/(g^2 - 2 Log[g] - 1), b -> g/(1 - g)} // FullSimplify` not gives zero, but gives

```
(I (Log[1/g] + Log[g]) (5 + 39 g^2 - 63 g^4 + 19 g^6 + 
     48 Log[1/g]^2 (-1 + g^2 - 2 Log[g]) + 
     12 Log[1/
       g] (-5 + 3 g^2 + g^4 - 4 Log[g]) (-1 + g^2 - 2 Log[g]) + 
     12 Log[g] (-10 + 21 g^2 - 6 g^4 + 
        2 (-4 + g^2) Log[g])))/(24 (-1 + g)^2 (-1 + g^2 + 
     2 Log[1/g]) (-1 + g^2 - 2 Log[g])^2)
```

The first multiplier in this expression is `(Log[1/g] + Log[g])=0` for `0<g<1`, but Mathematica not evaluates it to 0 with `//FullSimplify`.We can add assumption to get 0 as follows

```
 FullSimplify[(c4 - c)/. {G -> (4*(1 - g)^2)/(g^2 - 2 Log[g] - 1), b -> g/(1 - g)}, Assumptions -> g > 0]

Out[]= 0
```

Comment: is the state "...only if determinant not equals zero..." correct? The system of homogenous linear equations represented by `mat` has a non-trivial solution when the matrix has zero determinant

Comment: @Enter Thank you for correct expression for `c`. System of linear equations `{equ1, equ2, equ3 == 0, equ4 == 0}` is not homogenous since `vec` in  `{vec, mat} = 
 CoefficientArrays[{equ1, equ2, equ3 == 0, equ4 == 0}, {C[1], C[2], 
   C[3], C[4]}]` has 4 nonzero elements.

Comment: how can we see "c4 equaling to c" explicitly, I try `(c4 - c)/. {G -> (4*(1 - g)^2)/(g^2 - 2 Log[g] - 1), b -> g/(1 - g)} // FullSimplify` which does not give 0

Comment: @Enter It gives long expression with `(Log[1/g] + Log[g])` multiplier that equals zero for real `g`.   Please, see update to my answer.

Comment: Sir, sorry for a further question: can Mathematica simplify `c4` to the simpler form of `c` as given? I have tried `Factor` and manual derivation but still can't reduce it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Actually `c4-c=0` only on the line `{G -> (4*(1 - g)^2)/(g^2 - 2 Log[g] - 1), b -> g/(1 - g)},C[4]->0}`, but we can define `C[4]` from equation `c4-c==0`.  Then it is not clear how do you define `c`?

Answer (score 1):

This is an extended comment rather than a full answer.

In the method 2 part of the OP you stated **But, it gives null.**. Ok, so let's run a quick diagnostic check.

```
op[r_] = (D[#, {r, 2}] - 1/r*D[#, r]) &;
f0[r_] = 1/2*(2 r^2 Log[r/b] - r^2 + b^2);

eqn = op[r][
    op[r][f1[r]]] == -I*(4 - 2*G*(1 + b)^2*Log[r/b] + 
      G/2*(r^2 - b^2)*(1 + (1 + b)^2/r^2));
f1[b] == 0;
f1'[b] == 0;
bc3 = f1''[r] - 1/r*f1'[r] + G*(c*f0[r] - f1[r]);
bc4 = f0'[r] - I*(f1'''[r] - 1/r*f1''[r] + 1/r^2*f1'[r]) + 
   f0[r]/(1 + b)^2;
```

This is the important bit. We use the value for the constant `c` that you provided as the right answer in the OP.

```
c = I*G/4 (G/192*(1 + 2*b)^2*(41 + 82*b + 30*b^2) - 
      1/8*(1 + 2*b + 5*b^2)*(3 + 6*b + 2*b^2) - 
      3/4*(1 + b)^2*(1 + 2*b)*
       Log[(1 + b)/b] + (1 + b)^4*(Log[(1 + b)/b])^2) - 
   I/(2*(1 + b))*(1/8*((1 + 2*b)/(1 + b))^2 - 1);
```

So, we want to `DSolve` with all boundary conditions and the answer for `c` to see if we can get a consistent answer.

```
DSolve[{eqn, 
     f1[b] == 0, (f1'[r] /. r -> b) == 0, (bc3 /. r -> b + 1) == 
      0, (bc4 /. r -> b + 1) == 0}, f1[r], {r}, 
    Assumptions -> b > 0 && {b, G} ∈ Reals] // Flatten // 
  Factor // Simplify
```

The above returns an answer that does not appear to have any issues. It is what I call `f11[r]`. Since the output is too long and it does not take to execute this in Mathematica, I do not provide its explicit expression.

Returning to the task at hand. You have a fourth order differential equation and four boundary conditions. If you attempt to do a DSolve with all you will get a “nice” answer. So, we want to execute:

```
DSolve[{eqn, 
      f1[b] == 0, (f1'[r] /. r -> b) == 0, (bc3 /. r -> b + 1) == 
       0, (bc4 /. r -> b + 1) == 0}, f1[r], {r}, 
     Assumptions -> b > 0 && {b, G} ∈ Reals] // Flatten // 
   Factor // Simplify;
```

The output of the above computation is what I call `f1[r]`. Please note, that I did try to use `FullSimplify` but it was taking too long to finish.

Let me pose my question at this point. The constant `c` that you want to obtain and for which you provided a value to check appears in the expression for `bc3`. The only known thing about `bc3` is that it vanishes at `r=b+1`, so it does not leave much to proceed. The constant `c` appears, also, in the solution for `f1[r]`, but again the only information is that the function and its derivative vanish at `r=b`. I am wondering if there's any extra stuff that perhaps you forgot to include in the OP and would allow us to proceed. In any case, you can have the solution for `f1[r]` without any undetermined coefficients.

Finally, one can try to compare the two solutions we discussed above, namely

```
(f1[r] // Factor // Simplify) - (f11[r] // Factor // Simplify) // 
   Factor // Simplify // FullSimplify
```

yields

> 

```
(I G (-1 - 2 b + 
     2 (1 + b)^2 Log[
       1 + 1/b]) (48 (7 + 12 b + 4 b^2 + 16 I (1 + b)^3 c) - 
     24 (1 + b)^3 (3 + 2 b (3 + b)) (1 + b (2 + 5 b)) G + (1 + 
        b)^3 (41 + 82 b + 30 b^2) (G + 2 b G)^2 + 
     48 (1 + b)^5 G Log[
       1 + 1/b] (-3 - 6 b + 4 (1 + b)^2 Log[1 + 1/b])) ((b - r) (b + 
        r) + 2 r^2 (-Log[b] + Log[r])))/(1536 (1 + b)^3 (4 + G + 
     2 b G + 2 (1 + b)^2 G (Log[b] - Log[1 + b])))
```

Comment: before executing the 2nd `DSolve`, we need to `Clear[c]` first, right?

Comment: Thank you for the help! may i comment on "The only known thing about bc3 is that it vanishes at r=b+1, ... but again the only information is that the function and its derivative vanish at r=b,...". Actually, `bc4` relates the 1st, 2nd and 3rd-order derivatives of `f1` and thus involves `c` implicitly, so can we proceed with `bc4` somehow? Btw, I am sorry for a typo in the last term of `c` (updated).

Comment: I have double-checked the problem and do not find any other useful information... Well, as Alex mentioned, a physically meaningful solution should be bounded `Norm[f1]<Infinity`. Btw, could you suggest any kind of extra conditions that would allow us to proceed?

Comment: If we evaluate last expression as `%/. {G -> (4*(1 - g)^2)/(g^2 - 2 Log[g] - 1), 
   b -> g/(1 - g)} // FullSimplify` we got answer `ComplexInfinity`. See my answer for clarification.

Comment: @DiSp0sablE_H3r0 with the typo in `c` being corrected, your last expression is evaluated to zero, which means `c` should have been determined by the given conditions. Am i right?

Comment: @Enter I overslept today, so give me some time to check corrections and I will get back to you.